# PHP - Mixed array into Indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
$transport = array(
  "Car" => array('Volvo','BMW','Saab','Land Roover'),
  array("Air Plane"),
  "Boat" => array('Ship','Yacht','Sail Boat'), 
  array("Bicycle")
);

print_r($transport);
echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
```

How can I write a function that will turn array `$transport` into array `$transport_in_array`?
The goal is to wrap all elements of `$transport` inside an array so that the `$transport_in_array` becomes indexed.

```
$transport_in_array = array(
  array("Car" => array('Volvo','BMW','Saab','Land Roover')),
  array("Air Plane"),
  array("Boat" => array('Ship','Yacht','Sail Boat')),
  array("Bicycle")
);

print_r($transport_in_array);
```

Comment: `$transport` _is_ indexed, it just has mixed key types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to it can be done in simple loop:

```
$transport = array(
  "Car" => array('Volvo','BMW','Saab','Land Roover'),
  array("Air Plane"),
  "Boat" => array('Ship','Yacht','Sail Boat'), 
  array("Bicycle")
);

$transport_in_array = array();
foreach ($transport as $key=>$value) {
    $transport_in_array[] = is_string($key) ? array($key => $value) : $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$transport=array_map(function($k, $v) {
    return is_int($k) ? $v : array($k => $v);
}, array_keys($transport), $transport);
```